# Filter Mat-Table based on Multiple select drop down

Tags: angular, material-design

I need to filter mat-table data based on the drop-down selections. So I have added a customized filter but filtering is not working properly since I'm using Multiple options in mat-select dropdown I'm getting values in an array and not sure how to filter the values. Can someone plz help me.

```html
<mat-form-field class="view-filter">
    <mat-select placeholder="Sub Value" [FormControl]="subValueFormControl" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let subVal of subValueOptions" [value]="subVal">
            {{subVal}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Assigning data source from http service .

```js
filterValues = {
    SubValue: "",
    Horizontal: "",
    ID: ""
};

this.dataSource.data = [{
    SubValue: "AA",
    Horizontal: "In-1",
    ID: "1"
},
{
    SubValue: "BB",
    Horizontal: "In-2",
    ID: "2"
},
{
    SubValue: "CC",
    Horizontal: "In-2",
    ID: "2"
},
{
    SubValue: "DD",
    Horizontal: "In-1",
    ID: "1"
}];
```

```js
ngOnInit(){
    if (this.dataSource) {
        this.subValueFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(SubValue => {
            this.filterValues.SubValue = SubValue;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
        });

        this.horizontalFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(Horizontal => {
            this.filterValues.Horizontal = Horizontal;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
        });
        this.idFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(ID => {
            this.filterValues.ID = ID;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
        });

        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.tableFilter();
    }
}
```

Tried changing the value to toLowerCase as well but still filter is not wokring . Here the value of searchTerms is like this incase of single drop down selection

```js
searchTerms = {
    SubValue: ["AA"],
    Horizontal: ["In-1"],
    ID:["1"]
}
```

when multiple selection has made in dropdown

```js
searchTerms = {
    SubValue: ["AA","BB"],
    Horizontal: ["In-1","In-2"],
    ID:["1"]
}
```

```js
public tableFilter() {
    const filterFunction = function (data, filter): boolean {
        const searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
        return (
            data.SubValue.indexOf(searchTerms.SubValue) !== -1 ||
            data.Horizontal.indexOf(searchTerms.Horizontal) !== -1 ||
            data.ID.indexOf(searchTerms.ID) !== -1
        );
    };
    return filterFunction;
}
```

How can I filter data based on these multiple drops down selections? Please help me .

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhacoa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could create a working stackblitz of the same.

Comment: Plz find the link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhacoa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TypeScript version:**

```js
private createFilters<T>(): (data: T, filter: string) => boolean {
  const filterFunction = function (data: T, filter: string): boolean {
    const searchTerms: Partial<Record<keyof T, string>> = JSON.parse(filter);

    if (searchTerms === null || searchTerms === undefined) {
      return true;
    }

    return Object.keys(searchTerms).every((key) => {
      if (Array.isArray(searchTerms[key])) {
        return searchTerms[key]?.length > 0
          ? searchTerms[key].some((term: string) =>
              Array.isArray(data[key])
                ? data[key].includes(term)
                : data[key] === term
            )
          : true;
      }

      return (
        data[key]?.toLowerCase()?.indexOf(searchTerms[key]?.toLowerCase()) !==
        -1
      );
    });
  };

  return filterFunction;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your filter, you are checking the data incorrectly.

Let's take `searchTerms.SubValue` for example, `searchTerms.SubValue` is an array and `data.SubValue` is your value from the table. In your filter, you are doing `data.SubValue.indexOf(searchTerms.SubValue) !== -1`. This will check whether `searchTerms.SubValue` exists in `data.SubValue` which is incorrect. We need to this to work the other way around. So your code should be `searchTerms.SubValue.indexOf(data.SubValue) !== -1` instead. You will have to update the other conditions accordingly as well.

This will make your filter work but when there are no conditions selected, the filter will filter out the entire table. To avoid this, we will place a check to return the entire table in case there are no filter values.

Here's how your filter will now look.

```js
public tableFilter() {
    const filterFunction = function (data, filter): boolean {
        const searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);

        // return all data if there are no filter values
        if (!searchTerms.SubValue.length && !searchTerms.Horizontal.length && !searchTerms.ID.length) {
            return true;
        }

        return (
            searchTerms.SubValue.indexOf(data.SubValue) !== -1 ||
            searchTerms.Horizontal.indexOf(data.Horizontal) !== -1 ||
            searchTerms.ID.indexOf(data.ID) !== -1
        );
    };
    return filterFunction;
}
```

On a side note, avoid using variable names that begin with capital letters. Use camelCase instead (`subValue`, `horizontal` and `id`).

Answer (score 0):

Find sample code below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //will be assigned data from httpcall 
    var filData = [];
    filData = this.tableDataSource;

      this.dataSource.data = this.tableDataSource;

      this.subValueFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(SubValue => {
          this.filterData(SubValue,'sub');
    });

    this.horizontalFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(Horizontal => {
        this.filterData(Horizontal,'hor')
    });
    this.idFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(ID => {
        this.filterData(ID,'id');
    });

  }

   filterData(filterValue,type){
       let subValueFilterData= [];
      for(var i=0;i<filterValue.length;i++) {
      this.tableDataSource.filter(item => {
        if(type === 'sub') {
            if(item.SubValue === filterValue[i]) {
              subValueFilterData.push(item);
              return;
            }
        } else if (type === 'hor') {
            if(item.Horizontal === filterValue[i]) {
              subValueFilterData.push(item);
              return;
            }
        } else if(type === 'id') {
             if(item.ID === filterValue[i]) {
              subValueFilterData.push(item);
              return;
            }
        }
      });
      }
      if(subValueFilterData.length==0) {
        this.dataSource.data = this.tableDataSource;
      } else {
        this.dataSource.data = subValueFilterData;
      }

  }
```